# Need to give a non-privileged user permission to execute apachectl script

Tags: apache-2.4, httpd, sudo

I want that a regular user to be able to execute apachectl in the system. And that would be the only thing that they can do outside of it normal permissions. What I did is to add this line at the bottom of the sudoers file:

```
sampleuser ALL=(root)      NOEXEC:/usr/sbin/apachectl
```

So, as the user sampleuser, I executed `apachectl` command, and I get this error:

`sudo apachectl stop 
[sudo] password for sampleuser: 
/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 105: /usr/sbin/httpd: Permission denied`

Now it seems like the permission is with the /usr/sbin/httpd command since `apachectl` script calls that executable file. So I added another line to the sudoers file:

```
sampleuser ALL=(root)      NOEXEC:/usr/sbin/httpd
```

Now I executed the same command and I get the same error:

`sudo apachectl start
[sudo] password for sampleuser: 
/usr/sbin/apachectl: line 105: /usr/sbin/httpd: Permission denied`

My question now, is that if there's a fix for this without having to edit the apachectl script file or another method that probably is easier than what I'm trying to do.

Thank you.

Comment: What Linux distribution and version is this?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Amazon Linux AMI release 2017.09